# Реализация FIFO на python 2.x

Tags: python, python-2.x, fifo

Нужно реализовать метод `FIFO` на `Python 2.x`. Я реализовал таким образом, что я не учел?

Если это нормальный вариант реализации, то возможно ли сделать лучше и как это сделать? (Только касательно логики)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mas = []

    def append_element(self, element):
        self.mas.append(element)

    def get_element(self):
        out = self.mas[0]
        del self.mas[0]
        print out
        return out

    def print_list(self):
        print self.mas
        
        
a = A()
a.append_element(5)
a.append_element("a")
a.get_element()
a.get_element()
a.print_list()
```

**P.S.**

Ограничения на количество элементов нет.

Comment: Вам именно своя реализация нужна? Стандартные классы `collections.deque()` или `queue.Queue()` не подойдут? В 2.х они тоже есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно чуть короче и с проверкой на непустоту

```
def get_element(self):
    if self.mas:
        out = self.mas.pop(0)
    else:
        out = None
    print out
    return out
```

Comment: Упс, что то я проморгал, спасибо. А другие косяки есть?

Comment: Ну не забудьте проверять на наличие хотя бы одного элемента при извлечении значения

Comment: `out = self.mas.pop(0) if self.mas else None` - попитонестей будет. :)